# How to add new fields to POS Receipt / How to inherit a js file

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11

I want to add new fields to POS Receipt.I want to do it by inheriting the js file in my custom module.I don't know js so I don't know how to inherit it.In odoo's file `point of sale > static > src > js > pos.js`

```
model:  'res.company',
fields: [ 'currency_id', 'email', 'website', 'company_registry', 'vat', 'name', 'phone', 'partner_id' , 'country_id', 'tax_calculation_rounding_method'],
ids:    function(self){ return [self.user.company_id[0]]; },
loaded: function(self,companies){ self.company = companies[0]; },
```

I edited fields and added my required field say `street2` and it is coming in `Pos Receipt`
I tried inheriting the js file but it is not working.
This is my code

```
var _super = module.PosModel.prototype;
module.PosModel = module.PosModel.extend({
 initialize: function (session, attributes) {
    _super.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.models.push({
        model:  'res.company',
        fields: ['street2'],
    })
    return this;
 },

});
```

I also create an xml file to show the path of js file.

> xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/xn_pos_vat_enhancement_v11/static/src/js/pos_receipt_fields.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Odoo Version : 11 (Community)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this by:

```
odoo.define('xn_pos_vat_enhancement_v11.pos_receipt_fields', function (require) {
    var models = require('point_of_sale.models');    
    var core = require('web.core');    
    var _t = core._t;    
    var session = require('web.session');
    var rpc = require('web.rpc');

    var _super_PosModel = models.PosModel.prototype;
    models.PosModel = models.PosModel.extend({
        get_model: function (_name) {
            var _index = this.models.map(function (e) {
                return e.model;
            }).indexOf(_name);
            if (_index > -1) {
                return this.models[_index];
            }
            return false;
        },
        initialize: function (session, attributes) {
            var self = this;            
            var company_model = this.get_model('res.company');
            company_model.fields.push('street','street2','state_id');            

            _super_PosModel.initialize.apply(this, arguments);          

        },        
        get_config: function () {
            return this.config;
        },        

    });

});
```

Where `xn_pos_vat_enhancement_v11` is my module name and `pos_receipt_fields` is my file name.
I don't know to explain the whole code,if anyone can I will accept their answer.